# Questions on Paypal opencart integration

Tags: php, paypal, opencart, express-checkout

I have integrated Paypal extensions (standard and express checkout) to my opencart. But I have few queries regarding the flow.

1. How can I enable direct credit card payments? I have already tried enabling it at accounts in developer console but I was shown this message:

   > Note: Direct credit card processing is not available for you when using REST APIs. Your live credentials are inoperable for direct credit card processing for your country but your test credentials are enabled for sandbox testing.
2. I am getting "*security header invalid*" error when I try to do a payment with expresscheckout. Not sure how where can I get exact API details
3. Is there any way I can implement paypal in-context flow in opencart?

Comment: SO is not a place for such questions, here you show your problem and what you have tried to solve it + your questions is about settings and configuration and it's not related to programming

Comment: They don't like these kind of questions here and they'll vote you down and kill your post.  If you want to [post here instead](https://www.angelleye.com/forum) I'll be happy to help.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm happy there are alternative places to post questions, but questions begging "ASAP" answers from volunteers should not be welcome anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

1) Only US, UK, Canada and Australia countries merchant can apply direct credit card payment. Based on your error message, it looks like your PayPal account doesn't belong to these countries. please correct me if I'm wrong.

2)"security header invalid" means the API credential is incorrect. Please get your API credential at https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_login-api-run  after login.

3) Refer to http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=123&t=147345 , there are some preconditions before you use in-context flow in opencart. You can confirm with opencart support team directly.

Hope these information could help you.